# ASP.NET how to bind all elements with certain class to the same data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

Let's say that I have 100 dropdownlists with the class "statuses". How can I bind all webcontrols with the class "statuses" to the same datasource instead of doing it one by one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Theoretically if you have 100 100 dropdownlists you gone need to have 100 datasource for each list

Comment: That's depressing :/ Are you sure I can't get a collection of all controls on the page with a particular class and give them a single data source?

Comment: By class, do you mean CSS class? Are your drop downs in some kind of repeater or other container? I'm trying to imagine a scenario where you would have 100 drop downs bound to the same data NOT in a repeater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All controls are located in [Page.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which you can iterate accordingly:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    LoopDropDownLists(Page.Controls);
}

private void LoopDropDownLists(ControlCollection controlCollection)
{
    foreach(Control control in controlCollection)
    {
        if(control is DropDownList)
        {
            ((DropDownList)control).DataSource = //Set datasource here!
        }

        if(control.Controls != null)
        {
            LoopDropDownLists(control.Controls);
        }
    }
}
```

I am however intrigued by your need for 100 DropDownLists, is this user friendly?

Answer (score 1):

On page load, you could loop through the controls on the form and dynamically set the data source property on the dropdown list to the desired source, based on the class property if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to m.edmondsons answer:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Bind DropDown Lists with a cetain CSS Class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control">Parent Control Containing Dropdown Lists</param>
    /// <param name="cssClass">Class that determines binding</param>
    /// <param name="tableToBind">Data Source</param>
    public void FindAndBindControlsRecursive(Control control, string cssClass, DataTable tableToBind)
    {   
        foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
        {
            if (childControl.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
            {
                DropDownList dd = (DropDownList)childControl;
                //Check CSS class                    
                if (dd.CssClass.IndexOf(cssClass) > -1)
                {
                    dd.DataSource = tableToBind;
                    //Set DataFields & TextFields
                    dd.DataBind();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                FindAndBindControlsRecursive(childControl, cssClass, tableToBind);
            }
        }
    }
```